# Width of scrollbar on hover not expanding

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to expand the scrollbar width on hover.
But I am getting this console error --> scrollbar.addEventListener is not a function

JAVASCRIPT

```
setTimeout(function()
{
  const scrollbar = document.querySelector('.articles-container::-webkit-scrollbar');
  scrollbar.addEventListener('mouseover', scon, false);
  scrollbar.addEventListener('mouseout', scout, false);
  function scon()
  {
     scrollbar.style.width = '30px';
  }
  function scout()
  {
     scrollbar.style.width = '20px';
  }

}, 1300);
```

Why am I getting this error --> scrollbar.addEventListener is not a function
Please help me

Comment: you need to use querySelector. querySelectorAll returns a NodeList. You can't add the listener on a list of nodes.

Answer (score 1):

This is because `document.querySelectorAll()` actually returns a NodeList (an array-like structure) which does not have this method (besides, to which element in the NodeList would you add it to?).

In order to fix your issue, you need to either use `document.querySelector()` (notice it does not terminate with `All`) or extract the element you want to attach the listener to `document.querySelectorAll()[<number>]`

Comment: Using only querySelector removes the error but not having any effect on scrollbar width. This is casing problem  `.articles-container::-webkit-scrollbar` without the pseudo selector it's working like only `.articles-container` - how can I get the scrollbar width expanded while only hovering on scrollbar not the entire container?